# AJAX Call: "Failed to load the content"

Tags: jquery, ajax

My Jquery code is below, but it is always giving 'Failed to load the content', i need to make an ajax call to get the data using rest api. I am using jQuery 1.3.2.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(function () {

var cat_id = ${coreNode.ancestors[0].id};
var restUrl = "http://xyz./restapi/vc/categories/id/"+cat_id+"/boards";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: restUrl,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    data: "DATA",
    success: function (response) {

    alert(restUrl);



      });



    },
    error: function (response) {

        $('#float-threads').html('Failed to load the content');

    }
});
});

</script>

<div id="float-threads">
</div>
```

Comment: What is the error? Does the url return with 404 maybe?

Comment: error is in url:'restUrl', remove the quote. and data: "DATA", you need to pass data as variable and assign value to it.

Comment: Also, if your purpose is to simply fetch data from the server, you should use GET instead of POST ;)

Answer (score 4):

You are passing string `'restUrl'` instead of a variable's value.

Remove the quotes here `url: 'restUrl',`.

Use `url: restUrl,`

Same as your DATA. It should be defined before and unquoted. Otherwise php will receive a string (word), instead of the content/value of that variable.

In your sucess function you have a extra `});` that should not be there. (Maybe part of other code you will have). So use:

```
success: function (response) {
    alert(restUrl);
 // }); - without this line
},
```

Comment: Edited it, but it is now giving an error at  }); after alert(restUrl);

Comment: @VarunLuthra, where did you get `});` after alert() from? I think you should remove that.

Comment: Check if your code is valid with [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) - sometimes it might throw an error because your parentheses aren't closed properly ;)

Comment: No Luck :( i have tried running it, but still showing Failed to load content

Comment: @VarunLuthra, in your url you do not point to a specific php file. Does the path exist? what error do you get on the console?

Comment: @Sergio The URL will be dynamic, based on the "cat_id" which will be generated on page load by ${coreNode.ancestors[0].id};

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
   var cat_id = ${coreNode.ancestors[0].id};
```

instead try to pass some hardcoded value to it and then check

```
    var cat_id = 1;
```